# $\vec{u}+\vec{v}-\vec{w},\;\vec{u}-\vec{v}+\vec{w},\;-\vec{u}+\vec{v}+\vec{w} $ are linearly independent if and only if $\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}$ are

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm consufed: how can I prove that $$\vec{u} + \vec{v} - \vec{w} , \qquad  \vec{u} - \vec{v} + \vec{w},\qquad - \vec{u} + \vec{v} + \vec{w} $$ are linearly independent vectors if, and only if $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ are linearly independent?

Ps: sorry for my poor English!

Comment: :ur English is good but what are u trying ?

Comment: u, v and w will be LI if they are = 0, right?

Comment: u, v, and w are said to be independent when the only solution to $$a\vec{u} + b\vec{v} + c\vec{w} = 0$$ is $$a=b=c=0$$\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:$$a(\vec{u} + \vec{v} - \vec{w})+ b (\vec{u} - \vec{v} + \vec{w})+c( - \vec{u} + \vec{v} + \vec{w})=0\\
\implies(a+b-c)\vec{u}+(a-b+c)\vec{v}+(-a+b+c)\vec{w}=0$$ then we have $$a+b-c=0 ,a-b+c=0 ,-a+b+c=0$$ From which we can easily conclude  $a=b=c=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the triple scalar product.  If the triple scalar product is zero, then the vectors are linearly dependent.

You should be able to verify that

$$(u + v - w) \cdot [(u - v + w) \times (-u + v + w)] = C u \cdot (v \times w)$$

for some nonzero constant $C$ (I believe it's $C = -4$). Thus, for the equation to be true, either both sets of vectors are linearly dependent, or neither set is.

Comment: Assuming that the underlying space is 3-dimensional. (Which is sufficient, since one may restrict to the space spanned by $u$, $v$ and $w$.)

Answer (score 0):

Call the three vectors $a, b, c$ then you find $2u=a+b, 2v=a+c, 2w=b+c$

If there is a linear dependence in $a, b, c$ the equations translate into a (nontrivial) dependence in $u, v, w$ and vice versa - the two sets of vectors are related by an invertible linear transformation.